# My application crashes on adding Aller font family's fonts like Bold,Regular and Italics

Tags: ios

I have properly added them into my plist and created a Custom UIFont class where i am overriding the system font with this Aller font.For the same code and same procedure if i am integrating Lato font it works fine.Problem is only with the Aller Font.

```
il passed to [UILabel setFont:] and [UILabel defaultFont] is also nil. Don't know what to do, so leaving font as (null) 0.000000
2014-12-18 15:33:50.715 2497:72343] Unable to load string table file: CFBundle 0x7fcfcae121a0 </Users/arun/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8A7E96AE-E960-4DAF-BD6F-79E533711C63/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/50D90A3E-10C5-4E02-A0D3-A1AAA86508D8.app> (executable, loaded) / Main: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)
2014-12-18 15:33:50.735 [2497:72343] nil passed to [UIButton setFont:] and [UIButtonLabel defaultFont] is also nil. Don't know what to do, so leaving font as (null) 0.000000
2014-12-18 15:33:50.737 [2497:72343] nil passed to [UIButton setFont:] and [UIButtonLabel defaultFont] is also nil. Don't know what to do, so leaving font as (null) 0.000000
2014-12-18 15:33:50.737[2497:72343] nil passed to [UILabel setFont:] and [UILabel defaultFont] is also nil. Don't know what to do, so leaving font as (null) 0.000000
2014-12-18 15:33:50.742[2497:72343] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: NSParagraphStyle)'
```

Comment: Have you tested that `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Aller something something" size:(CGFloat)]` actually returns a UIFont object? I've experienced that font names vary a lot from what you would expect :)

Comment: Yes i did and its not working.Still crashes with same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really disturbing situation .Even I had spent lot time on researching the solution.Finally got one especially for fonts like Aller,You can try this .It helped me.
Try checking the proper name of the Font by opening the font file it in Font Book and use the font name displayed there.

Comment: :- thanks a lot i wasted my 2 days on this issue.Thanks its working NOW.